# I'm able to calculate time, but it keeps resetting and does not add up time

Tags: discord.js

```js
const { Collection } = require("discord.js");
// ...
client.userStudyTime = new Collection();
client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (message.content === "!login") {
        // Check if the message's content was !login
        const time = new Date(); // Get the login time
        client.userStudyTime.set(message.author.id, time.getTime()); // Set the time
    }
    if (message.content === "!logout") {
        // Check if the message's content was !logout
        const userTime = client.userStudyTime.get(message.author.id); // Get the user's login time
        if (!userTime) return message.channel.send("You are not logged in!"); // Check if the user had logged in
        const time = new Date().getTime(); // Get the logout time
        const diff = time - userTime; // Calculate the difference
        const hours = Math.round(diff / 1000 / 60 / 60); // Get the hours
        const minutes = Math.round(diff / 1000 / 60); // Get the minutes
        const seconds = Math.round(diff / 1000); // Get the seconds
        message.channel.send(
            `You studied for ${hours}hrs, ${minutes}min, ${seconds}sec`
        ); // Reply back
        client.userStudyTime.set(message.author.id, null); // Set the collection to null
    }
});
// .
```

Comment: If you want to add up all the study time you will need a database. You can go through some tutorials for common databases, pick one which feels easy and has benefits for you and then just implement it in your code

Comment: quick.db module is a quick and simple database u can store locally, it uses .sqlite